# Replication is blocking the shrinkage og transacation log

Tags: sql-server

Can any body please help me with this issue.

On production my transaction log is growing and I am not able to shrink file because of the replication. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the log reader agent do its job. Make sure the distributor is running the log reader agent and reading the log. Check in Replication Monitor that the log reader agent is started and does not show errors. See these links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/chrissk/archive/2010/01/28/troubleshooting-transactional-replication-part-1.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/chrissk/archive/2010/01/28/troubleshooting-transactional-replication-part-2.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/chrissk/archive/2010/02/02/troubleshooting-transactional-replication-part-3.aspx
- [Replication Agents (Troubleshooting)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151872.aspx)